# How can I do Instr() function in Standard SQL (Non-Legacy) on Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

It appears I am unable to do Instr() in standard SQL on Big Query but have been unable to find an alternative function. Would really appreciate help with this.

example input:

```
John smith:hello
```

command:

```
SUBSTR(John smith:hello ,INSTR(John smith:hello ,
          ':')+1,LENGTH(John smith:hello))
```

required output:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo can use [`STRPOS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#strpos) function for this

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUBSTR('John smith:hello', STRPOS('John smith:hello', ':') + 1, LENGTH('John smith:hello'))
```

As an option - you can consider using [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) function

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('John smith:hello', r':(.*)')
```

both give same output:

```
hello
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed